# Correctly breaking out of jquery $.each() -- Is this a browser issue?

Tags: jquery, each

Why does the following work correctly in Firefox but NOT Chrome?   If I change the return value in the .each loop to 'true', it works in Chrome and not Firefox.  What gives?

(When it doesn't work, it only returns in seconds vs. the correct day,hour,etc.)

```
function time_remaining(expire_time)
    {
        var now = new Date().getTime()/1000,
        time_left = expire_time - now,
        time_left_str = '0 seconds';

        if (time_left < 1) {
            return time_left_str;
        }

        var a = {};
            a[ 12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 ] = 'year',
            a[      30 * 24 * 60 * 60 ] = 'month',
            a[           24 * 60 * 60 ] = 'day',
            a[                60 * 60 ] = 'hour',
            a[                     60 ] = 'minute',
            a[                      1 ] = 'second';


        $.each(a, function (secs, str) {
            var d = time_left / secs;
            if (d >= 1) {
                var r = Math.round(d);
                time_left_str = r + ' ' + str + ((r > 1) ? 's' : '');
                return false;
            }
        });

        return time_left_str;
    }
```

Comment: According to the docs `We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.`

Comment: Try using  return (fasle) as a callback to your function.. This should solve your problem as it will act like a break ;

Comment: I've tried both 'return false' and 'return (false)'.   This DOES work correctly on Firefox.  However, it DOES NOT work correctly on Chrome.  Chrome only works correctly when I use 'return true'..  not sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `$.each` problem, `var a = {};` is an object and `$.each(a, function (secs, str) {})` getting failed somehow because jQuery each function accept an array only.

need to convert `object` to `array` then use `$.each` function.

Added new code into function body for making `object` to `array`

```
// converting object to array
var temp = [];
var finalArr = [];
for (val in a) {
    temp.push(val);
}

temp = temp.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b
});
for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    finalArr.push(a[temp[i]] + "|" + temp[i]);
}
```

and also modified how to access data and index value of the new created array

```
 function time_remaining(expire_time) {
    var now = new Date().getTime() / 1000,
        time_left = expire_time - now,
        time_left_str = '0 seconds';

    if (time_left < 1) {
        return time_left_str;
    }

    var a = {};
    a[12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60] = 'year',
    a[30 * 24 * 60 * 60] = 'month',
    a[24 * 60 * 60] = 'day',
    a[60 * 60] = 'hour',
    a[60] = 'minute',
    a[1] = 'second';


    // converting object to array
    var temp = [];
    var finalArr = [];
    for (val in a) {
        temp.push(val);
    }

    temp = temp.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        finalArr.push(a[temp[i]] + "|" + temp[i]);
    }

    $.each(finalArr, function (secs, str) {
        var time = time_left / parseInt(str.split("|")[1], 10);

        if (time >= 1) {

            var randomNum = Math.round(time);
            time_left_str = randomNum + ' ' + str.split("|")[0] + ((randomNum > 1) ? 's' : '');
            return true;
        }
    });

    return time_left_str;

}
```

Comment: This does work.  Strange how Chrome and FF handle it differently.  Thanks KK.